Adding physical property tablespace to table not going into <table_properties>/tablespace
PD 16.7 - Oracle 12 Physical Model (PdPDM)
Im performing a vbscript automation to set a default tablespace for all tables
There is a confusing parameter in table property setting for setting a tablespace to a table
Function is "BaseTable".SetPhysicalOptionValue
There are two options

<physical_properties>/<standard>/tablespace

<table_properties>/tablespace


Table physical settings are blank when this happen... its the same result when only the missing setting is the <table_properties>/tablespace
When trying to set the latter <table_properties>/tablespace ,
it assumes by default to change to <physical_properties>/<standard>/tablespace
If the key already exists,
when  running "BaseTable".GetPhysicalOptionValue("<table_properties>/tablespace") it does indeed
get the data for the attribute, and setting works too!
Just a last test I did for the issue, and I discovered if I write twice / run the same write command, it indeed creates the right key, after creating the 'wrong' key.
What could I be missing? Why its defaulting to another key when it doesnt exist?
sub processa

   For each tbl in pkgs.tables
       tbl.SetPhysicalOptionValue("<table_properties>/tablespace","ABC"
   Next
end sub

it results a property named <physical_properties>/<standard>/tablespace ABC

You’re missing the start of the string on SetPhysicalOptionValue.

sorry, i didint understand what you refer about the start of the string.   are you talking about the double quote?  that was a typo

who knows if pascal is around to shed some light...

If it is a typo at least [edit] the question and fix the typo.

fixed. thanks for looking into the issue

I've made some progress so far..
The documentation is really lacking good examples ...  it wasnt clear to me how to deal with all the parameters ...  was looking to all functions and methods, but while looking into the XML when setting the string with all bells and whistles in the SQL tab, i could see the  BaseTale. property , which do not interfere at all with the data being handled, and can set/get properly
Basically its about this case..
https://sybase.public.powerdesigner.general.narkive.com/mkEe9Q6u/vbscript-to-inform-table-options
i wasnt able to grasp the link before, since the other methods were  running fine in one shot and not behaving when extending for more options.. i thought that i was doing it wrong and the end behaviour unexpected...
when dealing with options, its all about options and some respect powerdesigner version limitations
